# How can I connect C# with MySQL from Virtual Machine?

Tags: c#, mysql, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I setup a Linux virtual machine on Azure and deployed an Apache web server and MySQL. I have a C# application which I want to connect with the MySQL database from my virtual machine.
I installed the MySQL connector and followed tutorials like this:

```
   string connString = "Database=Virtual Machine IP;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=testing";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "Select * from Company";
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
                conn.Open();               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader["CompanyID"].ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

But it's not working as I receive this error: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.", so the connection was not successfully, does anyone know how to do it?

P.S. I tried the code with my database from the localhost and it worked.

Comment: Have you opened the proper ports on your Linux VM that hosts your MySQL instance?

Comment: Have you granted a firewall exception in azure for the ip address of the development machine trying to connect to dataserver and tried?

Comment: I have't use Azure before, the university provided us instruction how to setup a LAMP server so I don't know how to grant a firewall exception or which ports should be open and how to do it. I just need the database for my C# app. Could you please tell me the steps or provide a useful link?

Comment: ask your instructotors, your connection uses port 3306 to reach the database, but when this port isn't open, iz can't reach it.

Comment: @MonicaHotea - Please take a look at the Azure documentation. There is plenty of information regarding setting up inbound port rules for a virtual machine.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I enabled the port 3306, but I still receive the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

For the error, you probably need to enable the MySQL port 3306 in the inbound port rule of NSG. See this document: [How to open ports to a virtual machine with the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal).

For example, add the port 3306 in the **destination port ranges** and add your client public IP address to the **Source IP addresses** in the virtual network---networking---inbound port rules.

[image]

Comment: I enabled the port 3306, but I still receive the same exception.

Comment: Try to use [telnet to test the open ports](https://www.acronis.com/en-us/articles/telnet/) via `telnet vmpublicIP 3306`. When a computer port is open a blank screen will show up, meaning that the connection has been successful. What's the result on your side? Or run `netstat  --listening` to verify the listening port.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wanted to try your suggestion, but I didn't install the app.

Comment: Can you deploy another windows machine in the same subnet to try it? Telnet is a built-in features on windows VM. See more solutions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-troubleshoot-connectivity-problem-between-vms#step-3-check-whether-network-traffic-is-blocked-by-vm-firewall